# Using ftrace on Samsung smartphone

Tags: android, ftrace, samsung

I'm trying to read saved_tgids using adb:
cat sys/kernel/debug/tracing/saved_tgids in samsung A5 with Android 8,but i get "permission denied". Instead if i try to execute the command using adb: cat sys/kernel/debug/tracing/saved_tgids in Pixel 3a XL with Android 8, it shows something. Why?
The permission to access to file is the same:
-r--r--r--  1 root   root   0 1970-01-01 01:00 saved_tgids

Comment: Could you please tell us why you want to run ftrace so we can help better?

Comment: I want to set up ftrace tool in order to collect information regarding the system. I need to read saved_tgids file